# Visual Studio Code C++: unordered_map not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include-path

I was given some C++ files that I need to compile. I'm using Visual Studio Code with the C/C++ and Code Runner extensions on Windows 10. With the following "include" statements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <unordered_map>
```

I get the following error:

```
unordered_map: No such file or directory
```

I am very new to C++, and haven't been able to find a solution to this problem. I've updated the "includePath" in my c_cpp_properties.json file as follows. I have also tried compiling with Cygwin and Visual Studio Community, but I get the same error. I know the unordered_map .hpp file exists, but the compiler doesn't seem to be finding it.

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/include"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.17134.0",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

If it's relevant, this is what my tasks.json file looks like:

```
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "msbuild",
        "args": [
            // Ask msbuild to generate full paths for file names.
            "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
            "/t:build"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "presentation": {
            // Reveal the output only if unrecognized errors occur.
            "reveal": "silent"
        },
        // Use the standard MS compiler pattern to detect errors, warnings and infos
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
]
```

Are my .json files configured properly? I apologize if I'm missing something basic; I've done a lot of searching on how to compile C++ on Windows, and haven't had any success. Thank you in advance for any help.

**EDIT:**
Here is the full file I'm trying to compile. The executable is meant to be called by a python script.

https://github.com/jorpjomp/sierra-hotel/blob/master/location_routing.cpp

Comment: Visual Studio Community Edition should run out of the box if you created a standard c++ -> Win32 console project. I dunno why anyone would want to use VS code on Windows, but I might be naive. Can you show your entire .cpp file that you are trying to compile?

Comment: @ChristopherPisz Edited the post with the Github link. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So, if I download a fresh install of VS community, and create a new console project, and then plop your code in, it would need node.h and a definition for routingEntry. Just upload the entire project with solution file and all, to github, or put a MCVE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Don't dump your whole project/solution online and link it here. _Only_ provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Please add the project file and full compiler output (need to see the call parameters and compiler output)

Answer (score 1):

Unordered map is not supported in VS Code by default Microsoft ms-vscode.cpptools. Follow these steps to get over the problem:

1. Download MinGW from ( https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/ ). MinGW is a native Windows port of the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC), with freely distributable import libraries and header files for building native Windows applications.

   Mark all the packages for installation.
   [ss to mark all the packages for installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmD0O.png)

   Click on the Apply Changes option under the Installation tab
   [ss of where to click on apply changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBWj0.png)
2. Now, the Environment Variable’s Path is to be updated. Go to Advanced System Settings->Environment Variables.

   Edit Path in System Variables Tab.
   [ss of how to edit Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D86sg.png)

   Copy the path of the bin folder of MinGW. By default, the path is: C:\MinGW\bin

   Paste this new path in the list and click OK.
   [ss after pasting the bin path into the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aryf3.png)
3. Run the C++ code in VS Code. It will work fine.
   [ss of vs code working fine at last](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWT8V.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are using msbuild at the moment to build your project. Is this intentional? If you just have "some C++ files" you want to compile, msbuild is an overkill, compile the source directly by either using Mingw's g++ or the Microsoft CL.exe compiler.

So I recommend:

1) Go to http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download, download and install mingw and add the path to g++ into your PATH environment variable.

2) In Visual Studio Code create a task.json with the following content:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json (assuming you store mingw here: C:\mingw\mingw64\bin):

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/mingw/mingw64/bin",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```